# Change background color of selected div onclick not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a form's selected element change its background color upon click. When the page initially loads the first option is selected. I'm trying to figure out what is wrong with the code I have, because it loads CORRECT when its viewed in our page editor (we're using wordpress & elementor to build our pages and running this as custom html code), but doesn't not load correctly on a "live" page.

I've researched for other methods of doing this without much success, and am especially confused considering the page works - but only when viewed as an admin inside a page editor (elementor).

https://jsfiddle.net/ncLk85mb/

```
function toggleClass(el) {
    var kids = document.getElementById('menu1').children;
    for (var i = 0; i < kids.length; i++) {
        kids[i].className = "item";
    }
    el.className = "item highlight";
}
```

Above is the code I'm attempting to use to do the highlighting. I've pasted the entirety of what we've got so far into jsfiddle at the link above.

Comment: Actually, I don't see any problem. Workaround you could declare toggleClass in `<script>` header to ensure it was declared first.

Comment: @Mukyuu not sure that's going to fix it actually, at least I just tried doing so without much success unfortunately

Comment: Try to copy your code in SO code snippet don't forget to import jquery and you would found no problem with your current code earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to add another function to add or remove `highlight` class. You already trigger `click` event on your `div` element so you have to just modify it like below -

```js
$(".item").on('click', function() {
  $('.item').removeClass('highlight');
  $(this).addClass('highlight');
  var item = $(this).find('input');
  item.trigger("click");
  if (item.prop("checked")) {
    item.prop('checked', true);
  } else {
    item.prop('checked', false);
  }

});

$("input:checkbox").on('click', function() {
  var $box = $(this);
  if ($box.is(":checked")) {
    var group = "input:checkbox[name='" + $box.attr("name") + "']";
    $(group).prop("checked", false);
    $box.prop("checked", true);
  } else {
    $box.prop("checked", false);
  }
});

$("input[name=submit]").on('click', function() {
  var redirect = $('input[name="product"]:checked').val();
  window.location.href = redirect;
});
```

```css
/*Funnel Template - Step 2 - Order Form */

.main-panel {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  min-height: 320px;
  width: 100%;
}

.main-panel h2 {
  font-size: 26px;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.main-panel .item {
  margin: 15.4px 0;
  padding: 8px 0;
  min-height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.main-panel .item p {
  margin: 0;
}

.main-panel .selection {
  float: left;
  width: 10%;
}

.main-panel .left-section {
  float: left;
  width: 46%;
}

.main-panel .right-section {
  float: right;
  width: 37%;
  margin-left: 5%;
  text-align: right;
}

.main-panel .item.highlight {
  background-color: #ffc500;
  z-index: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.main-panel .item input[type='checkbox'] {
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  margin: 0;
}

.main-panel .item span::after {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1;
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  left: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #172969;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: border 0.15s ease-in-out, color 0.15s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: border 0.15s ease-in-out, color 0.15s ease-in-out;
  transition: border 0.15s ease-in-out, color 0.15s ease-in-out;
  line-height: 1.1em;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked+span:after {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  content: "\f00c";
  background-color: #172969;
  color: #fff;
}

input[type=button] {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-family: Noto Sans, sans-serif;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-panel">
  <form>
    <h2 style="text-align:center;">CHOOSE YOUR PACKAGE!</h2>
    <div id="menu1">
      <div class="item highlight">
        <div class="selection"><input type="checkbox" class="styled" name="product" value="#link1" checked="checked" /><span></span> </div>
        <div class="left-section">
          Option 1 A
        </div>
        <div class="right-section">
          Option 1 B
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="selection"> <input type="checkbox" name="product" value="link#2" /><span></span> </div>
        <div class="left-section">
          Option 1 A
        </div>
        <div class="right-section">
          Option 1 B
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="selection"> <input type="checkbox" name="product" value="#link3" /><span></span> </div>
        <div class="left-section">
          Option 1 A
        </div>
        <div class="right-section">
          Option 1 B
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="selection"> <input type="checkbox" name="product" value="#link4" /><span></span> </div>
        <div class="left-section">
          Option 1 A
        </div>
        <div class="right-section">
          Option 1 B
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <input type="button" name="submit" value="Click Now!" />
  </form>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/3s5vydhf/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Use `setAttribute`:

```
function toggleClass(el) {
    var kids = document.getElementById('menu1').children;
    for (var i = 0; i < kids.length; i++) {
        kids[i].setAttribute("class", "item");
    }
    el.setAttribute("class", "item highlight");
}
```

Comment: I went ahead and just tried swapping out the setAttribute option as you had it there but it doesn't seem to have worked? https://jsfiddle.net/9ktwbsyd/

Answer (score 0):

Use `element.classList.add()` instead.

```
function toggleClass(el) {
    var kids = document.getElementById('menu1').children;
    for (var i = 0; i < kids.length; i++) {
        kids[i].classList.add("item");
    }
    el.classList.add("item");
    el.classList.add("highlight");
}
```